# About a solid which satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=0, |x_i|\le1\ (i=1,2,\cdots,n)$

Tags: euclidean-geometry

For $n\ge 2\in\mathbb N$, let $S_n$ be the volume of a $(n-1)$ dimensional solid which satisfies 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=0, |x_i|\le1\ (i=1,2,\cdots,n).$$

Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : Can we represent $S_n$ by $n$ ?

**Motivation** : I've been interested in this simple question. I've got the followings :

$$S_2=2\sqrt 2, S_3=3\sqrt 3, S_4=\frac{32}{3}.$$

$S_4$ is the volume of a regular octahedron, whose edge length is $\sqrt 8$, which passes through the following six points :

$$(1,1,-1,-1),(1,-1,1,-1),(1,-1,-1,1),(-1,1,1,-1),(-1,1,-1,1),(-1,-1,1,1).$$

However, I don't have any good idea for $n$ in general. Can anyone help?

Update : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148980/about-a-solid-which-satisfies-sum-i-1nx-i-0-x-i-le1-i-1-2-cdots-n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting an answer just to inform that the question has received an answer by Igor Rivin on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148980/about-a-solid-which-satisfies-sum-i-1nx-i-0-x-i-le1-i-1-2-cdots-n).